Error en Flutter con Java
Tengo java 17, la variable de entorno ya está configurada, no sé que hacer, ando trabajando con flutter:(, ayuda plssss
PS C:\Users\DOLPHIN\Documents\U\que sa\quesale> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':path_provider_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':path_provider_android:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\DOLPHIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\DOLPHIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\DOLPHIN\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}
 
* Try:
   > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
   > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
   > Run with --scan to get full insights.
   > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
 
BUILD FAILED in 43s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
 


Saludos, por favor agrega el error en formato de texto. ;)

no me deja añadir un texto tan grande, te adjunto en texto mediante pastebin
https://pastebin.com/NJyVvDwG
si puedes ayudarmepls:(

Las preguntas dejan añadir cualquier cantidad de texto... no así de código. Pero un error, no es código...  no lo formatees como código y ya está. Las preguntas deben ser AUTOCONTENIDAS, es decir, todo lo relativo a la pregunta DEBE estar incluido en la misma. Si el día de mañana ese pastebin deja de tener tus datos, esta pregunta dejará de ser útil. Y no trabajamos para ti solo, trabajamos para toda la comunidad.

Correción: Donde dice "Si el día de mañana ese pastebin ... " debe decir "Cuando mañana ese pastebin ... "

Te sugiero configurar Android Studio para usar Java 17
Abre Android Studio.
Ve a File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle.
En "Gradle JDK", selecciona la ruta a tu instalación de Java 17.

Guarda los cambios y reinicia Android Studio.
